# Get Apache configure line

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

Is there any way to get the configure line that was used to build an Apache installation from source?

I compiled Apache 2.2.14 a while ago on Ubuntu and I can't remember the `./configure` line I used to build it. Is there any way I can retrieve it?

Comment: Bash history maybe?

Comment: Nah that's long gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the source directory in which you compiled is available, look for the file `config.nice`, which would contain a nice list of the configuration.

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# Created by configure

"./configure" \
"--prefix=/opt/apache" \
"--enable-rewrite" \
"--enable-so" \
"--enable-mime-magic" \
"--enable-cgi" \
"--enable-cache" \
"--enable-ssl" \
"--enable-proxy" \
"--enable-proxy-http" \
"--enable-proxy-balancer" \
"$@"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help, but I'm not sure how you missed the answer just above yours and my first comment to it that's been there for almost a year now.

Comment: anomareh: Not really. My answer is different. I happened to wrongly state `config.log`, whereas it should have been `config.nice`. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The GNU build tools output a config.log that starts something like:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU MP configure 5.0.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure
```

It's too much to hope that Apache's Autoconf does the same?

Comment: Where would that file be stored? My guess would be the folder I extracted the source too and installed from. In which case, I deleted that folder quite some time ago :s -- I was hoping for something in the fashion of how you can get PHP's config line from `phpinfo()`. Or possibly through some command.

Comment: The directory configure was in when it was run.  If you've deleted that directory, this is a completely useless suggestion...

Comment: for the record config.log was created for my apache compilation (so this is very useful if the source directory hasn't been removed).

Answer (score 1):

Try `apache2 -V`

This is on a default Ubuntu installation:

```
# apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov 13 2009 21:56:01
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:15
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.2.12
Compiled using: APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.2.12
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
  forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
  -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
  -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
  -D APR_HAS_MMAP
  -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
  -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
  -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
  -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
  -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
  -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
  -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
  -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
  -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
  -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
  -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
  -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
  -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
  -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
  -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

Comment: Yeah I found that command but it doesn't really help. I think the info under `Server compiled with....` is generic info. For instance my installation has an almost identical response though I know I specified a few options like `--enable-rewrite` and `--enable-so`

Comment: they are modules.. you can view modules that were compiled in with `apache2 -l`. So if you run `apache2 -V && apache2 -l` that should give you everything that was compiled during ./configure

Comment: Yeah I'm aware they're modules. I suppose it's enough to patch together what was most likely the config line if there's nothing else. Does `-l` only display modules that were compiled statically or will things like `--enable-rewrite=shared` show up there as well? I wouldn't think so but I'm not sure.

Comment: It will just list the name of the modules that were compiled into Apache2. Anything like --enable-rewrite=shared would probably only show up as mod_rewrite.c. Sorry if it's not as informal as you'd like, but that's the only way I can think of. I usually keep a history of every piece of software I compiled and step-by-step on how I did it for future reference. Perhaps you will now too :-D

Comment: Yeah definitely. I'm still kind of new to *nix and all this stuff. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 -Compiling and Installing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html) :
To upgrade across minor versions, start by finding the file `config.nice` in the `build` directory of your installed server or at the root of the source tree for your old install. This will contain the exact [configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/configure.html) command line that you used to configure the source tree.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a php enabled apache, you can also create a [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) file and see the Configure Command.

Comment: How would I do that?  Please add a little more detail on how this is done.

Comment: That will give the ./configure line used to prepare the PHP compilation, not the Apache one.